# Let users comment on categories in WordPress

Tags: comments, categories

I'm working with a client who wants visitors to be able to post comments on categories instead of on individual posts, but I am unsure on how to go about it. Is it possible to display the comment form in a category? Just pasting in `<?php comments_template(); ?>` didn't do it, unfortunately.

Comment: I assume you are pasting it under "category.php" ....will it be possible if u show the code that where you are placing this chunk of code

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/D4KZEMcp

Comment: Place <?php comments_template(); ?> right above the <?php endwhile; ?> --this is somewhere around line 79 and let me now if it works or not

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Also, wouldn't that connect the comments form to the posts in the category? I don't want the comments to be connected to the posts in the category, but to the category itself.

Answer (score 0):

For all I know, that's not possible, since comments depend on a Post ID to exist.

You can, however, mimic that functionality by registering a post_type to be at the same time, attached to one specific category, and parent their comments.

Then you can insert a secondary query on your `comments.php` to fetch the post_type entry associated with the current category and display its comments by that category's posts.

Answer (score 0):

i have found this answer [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comments-on-category-page)
tried it and it worked for a clean template i expriment on

here is the code:

```
<?php
$wp_query->is_single = true;
comments_template('/comments-slide.php');
$wp_query->is_single = false;
?>
```

.
Hope this helps...
Sagive

p.s - i would read the original answer to learn more